# unity click on object behind sprite

Tags: unity-game-engine, click, raycasting

I'm making a clicker game and every time I tap my screen an image pops out and falls down, the problem here is that every time I tap and hit one of these images the tap doesn't register.

I tried adding the used image prefabs in the ignore.Raycast layer but this doesn't solve my problem

Comment: How are you detecting these taps? Do you have any scripts that are part of this process? It's much easier to help if you provide a [simple, self-contained example](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Add a canvas group component to a parent object and set the ignore raycast value on that object.  I don't believe the new UI cares about the Ignore Raycast layer but I could be wrong.